# GTM incorrectly assigns cookies consent

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have GTM in consent mode. When I use JavaScript to set the default values, it first sets them correctly, but then runs GTM Built in Event: Consent Initialization and overwrites my settings so that everything is enabled.

Is there any way to disable this built in GTM consent initializatio  so that my settings remain?

How I set default consent:

```
let consent = {
  ad_storage: "denied",
  analytics_storage: "denied",
  functionality_storage: "granted",
};

window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}

gtag("consent", "default", consent);
```

GTM script:

```
  <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
      });
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-ID');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

[image: GTM]